# How to load custom php pages from a template

Tags: php, templates

I want to load all of my content pages off of one (or several depending on media type) php template.  For simplicity sake lets just walk through one content type.

As of right now I have all of my content in text files, I plug it into individual divs.  Each div is contained within a link that directs to its own php file. This seems extremely redundant and I'd like to cut out these extra php files.

[image: You can see I am maintaining txt files and php files]

The php template I use is simple and pulls in the text file that I manually plug in with this line of code.  file() pulls out every line in target file and stores each line as an index in the array $myContent.

```
 <?php
    $myContent = file("contentTxt/006wakeWeRide.txt");
 ?>
```

Then I run down the data, and plug it into html accordingly.

The text files have some headers that I pull relevant data from followed by lines that contain the body of the writing.

```
  1: txt                         //(type)
  2: The Wake We Ride            //(title)
  3: SumOne                      //(Author)
  4: 11/2017                     //(date)
  5: ./mats/philos.png           //(thumbnail)
  6: ./content/006wakeWeRide.php //(link to php file)
  7..8..: Paragraphs go here     //(content)
```

What I want, is to keep and maintain just the txt files, and to have them all refer to one template. After an hour of research I think I need to implement some sort of a GET request?  And somehow pass the text file to load too it. Im not sure how to do this.  Linking  to the external php is easy.  How do I link the user to the page while generating it?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but it seems to me as easy as this: `$file = $_GET['file']; $myContent = file("contentTxt/". $file .".txt");` and then a user simply browses towards `yoursite.com/phpfile.php?file=006wakeWeRide`

Comment: @icecub  What can I elaborate on to not lose people?

Comment: Currently I am having a user browse too the exterior php page via a link.  How do I get initiate browsing without the physical link?

Comment: There is such a thing as explaining too much. Try to stick to the actual problem. Explain what you've tried. What the result of it was and what the result should be. It's not relevant for us to know that you have links in individual divs etc etc. It distracts from the core problem :)

Comment: As of right now, I just don't fully understand what it is that you're trying to achieve. What I understood was that you want a single PHP file to load any of the TXT files based on which file the user requests?

Comment: @icecub I'ts tough to know what to explain with limited experience like mine.   I think that you comment is a solution to my problem, I just need to understand it a bit better.  Im gonna look into that a bit, and then maybe I can reformulate (or solve) my issue.  :)

Comment: It's ok. I'm just giving you some advise, that's all. Some info might actually be important and my lack of understanding the question makes it look like it's not. I'm not a saint. I make mistakes too :P I hope it'll help you out.